# React Native tab view inside a scrollview

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-tab-view

[expo demo](https://snack.expo.dev/QpTA8FNzs)

I'm trying to use react-native-tab-view with scrollable content, but having the tabview start half way down a scrollable page like:

```
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <SomeContent />
        <TabView
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            initialLayout={initialLayout}
            style={{flex: 1}}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

However when I run this on ios nothing renders below the tabs.
If I remove the top level scrollview then the whole thing will render but obviously only the tab itself is scrollable.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

this issuse almost drove me crazy, this is the solution:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <SomeContent />
        <TabView
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            initialLayout={initialLayout}
            style={{height:1000}}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

add height to your tab view and it would work

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with [react-native-tab-view v3](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/1349)
You can temporary downgrade to v2 (react-native-tab-view@2.16.0).